# Patent of prototype

Tags: patentability, technology

Our team is working on a prototype of C3P0 from the famous series STAR WARS. The features added in our prototype are quite different from the one shown in the movies. Will we be able to file a patent for our prototype?

Answer (score 2):

If it distinguishes in a non obvious manner over the known prior art (C3PO and other known robots) - yes. (You can file the patent no matter what, but that's the requirement for having the patent granted)'

If you want to sell your product, the name and design are probably protected, so you would have to take care of that issue, but for patentability that doesn't matter.

As the function of the robot isn't shown in the movies, they will probably not even be the relevant prior art. Other robots from the real world will be described in more detail and come closer to yours, so for the assessment of novelty and non obviousness, they will probably matter more. If you want a design patent too, the movies could be relevant though.

Comment: Good answer, but you might want mention searching for other prior art.

Comment: @EricShain what exactly do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that C3PO isn't the only prior art to be considered. There easily could be many robotic patents related to the "improvements" being considered for patenting.

Comment: I suppose your last paragraph cover this.